# Hint to prove that $-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$ is a convex function in the interval $[0 ,\pi/2]$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Can you give me a hint on proving the function $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$  is a convex function in the interval $[0 , \pi/2]$?

I am familiar with Jensen's inequality and second order derivative, but I couldn't apply them here.

Comment: Try taking the second derivative and proving it is positive.

Comment: @msinghal , I had tried second derivative and it boils down to proving $3x^4-3 \sin^4(x) -2x^4\sin^2(x) $ is non-negative. It is clear why it is nonnegative without third term, but I couldn't prove the whole expression is nonnegative.

Comment: Apologies. I noticed half way through. I agree with that expression.

Comment: Have you tried Taylor series?

Comment: @msinghal taylor series works, thanks.